# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError when I configure c3p0

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, gwt, c3p0

I've developed my GWT application (already configured with Hibernate 3.3.1.GA) with eclipse Photon (configured with Hibernate Tools 4.0.1). 
Now my goal is to configure c3p0  in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

When I launch my Hibernate code configuration in Eclipse (configured with 3.5 version) I get this error:

> Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources

I've already added to my project these jar files:

- c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar
- hibernate3.jar

If I change the configuration version of hibernate (from 3.5 to 4.0) this I don't get this error but when I launch my application it appers too much slow.

Comment: are you using maven? If yes can you try excluding c3p0 from hibernate's dependency ?

Comment: @Akash No. I not used Maven

Comment: If you would prefer, you can join our GWT community here https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt and you will get the best answers direct from GWT developers